# When will I be able to complete Underground Undercover, when waiting for Z1-14?

Tags: fallout-4

I have been trying to finish the main story with the Railroad. I am on the quest Underground Undercover, and am currently waiting for Z1-14, but it is taking some time for Z1-14 to contact me.

It seems like I am finishing the game as the Institute. When will I be able to continue the main story with the Railroad?

Comment: Obviously not a case of unclear, given that the question was clearly answered, and the answer accepted by the user.

Comment: @Timelord64 Someone managing to guess the correct answer doesn't make the question clearer.  It just means someone managed to dig through the gibberish and answer what they thought the question asked.  That said, you've now edited the question, which is a *fantastic* way to ensure it gets reopened.

Comment: @Frank, if they guessed it, good for them. OP confirmed it, so there is no question of intent. It was not hard to understand the question, given one simply took the time to read it, instead of merely skimming through, as you so commonly do

Comment: @Timelord64 You really should stop accusing me of sloppy work.  Look at who closed it.  **I'm not in it**.  The point I'm making is that someone guessing the right answer doesn't invalidate the close votes.  It just means someone guessed the right answer.

Comment: @Frank, somebody didn't just guess the answer. They read over a low quality response, and took the time to edit it into something a little more readable. I would accuse the close voters of being sloppy if OP did not make a substantial change **after** the question was closed. I am accusing you of sloppy work because the original edit post-closure makes it very obvious what OP is asking, The only thing wrong was punctuation/grammar. We do not close questions for bad grammar, **we fix them**. Especially when it is as obvious as it is, here.

Comment: @Timelord64 And **again**, ***I had nothing to do with closure***.  But I will defend those that did, because **you have to assume good faith**.  I don't care how you use your votes, but you do **not** get to tell others that they used theirs wrong.  If someone wants to edit it, they can.  It is **not** a requirement.  You have your way of doing things, they have theirs.  We're all working together to make the site a better place, so lay off the accusations, alright?

Comment: @Frank, your proving my point. I am not accusing the voters as OP made the question more clear **after** it was closed. The voters seen an **original** question and the OP since turned it into an **easier to understand** question. Read the entire text. Your arguments make sense if half of what I say was omitted, so you are either failing to read that half, or extremely obtuse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37997/discussion-between-frank-and-timelord64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are on the quest [Underground Undercover](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Underground_Undercover), and you are at the step where you are waiting for Z1-14 to be ready for you.

That will happen once you finish the quest [Powering Up](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Powering_Up), which means that you will need to continue being loyal to the Institute. Otherwise you will fail the Underground Undercover quest, and won't be able to finish the game with the Railroad.